# How to free connections in Apache DBCP?

Tags: java, apache-commons-dbcp

I am calling `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource#getConnection`, then working with it, then calling `Connection#close()` when connection is not needed anymore.

Unfortunately, my pool grows infinitely and all connection are remain active.

How to put connection to idle, so pool could re-use it?

Comment: You can play with the `maxXxx` properties (`maxWaitTimeMillis`, `maxIdle`, `maxConnLifetimeMillis`, etc.) I'd suggest playing with `maxConnLifetimeMillis`. If you really must you can always call `invalidateConnection(Connection)`. (requires DBCP 2.1)

Comment: I wonder, why isn't it work out of the box? Isn't it intended to work as I do? 

To call invalidateConnection I need to have dataSource instance in code where I was closing connection, which is not always true (I can always know connection and statement from resultset, but not datasource)

Comment: I'm not a DBCP developer so I can't answer that, sorry. I'm only giving pointers. What you can do is the following, if your architecture allows it: `Connection c = basicDataSource.getconnection(); try { ... /* use c */ } finally { basicDataSource.invalidateConnection(c); }`. If your architecture doesn't allow it, maybe it's good to refactor to get there?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Why bother with a connection pool at all in that case? The performance will be terrible, and there will still be a bug causing the pool to keep filling up.

Comment: @Kayaman so how to avoid pool filling up?

Comment: This is why I said to properly configure the `BasicDataSource` with the appropriate values! The problem is that Dims didn't say how/when he wants to destroy the connections... The only moment you know for sure that you have a connection is right after using it. The configuration should be king!

Comment: @Dims I'd drop `DBCP` altogether. The last time I was checked a comparison on different connection pools, `DBCP` wasn't exactly top of the line. My choice is HikariCP.